# Mongo remove entire array from collection

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

Let's say I have this object saved:

```
{
  "_id" : "54122fe6965f599d211ea9ec",
  "cat": {
    "bla" : "foo"
  },
}
```

I have hundreds of entries, where I need to change the cat array, to say, something like:

```
{
  "_id" : "54122fe6965f599d211ea9ec",
  "animals" : {
    "cat": {
      "bla" : "foo"
    },
  }
}
```

So I then do an update with my new array, but, how can I delete the original cat array once I've updated it?, so now I'm left with:

```
{
  "_id" : "54122fe6965f599d211ea9ec",
  "cat": {
    "bla" : "foo"
  },
  "animals" : {
    "cat": {
      "bla" : "foo"
    },
  }
}
```

I've tried:

```
$this->database->$collection->remove(array('cat'));
```

But no luck yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has a an update operator called [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/). You just it in updating a document just as you would with the **`$set`** operator, but of course it does the opposite. Your query portion would need the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator logically:

```
$this->database->$collection->update(
    array( 'cat' => array( '$exists' => true ) ),
    array( '$unset' => array( 'cat' => 1 ) ),
    array( 'multiple' => true )
);
```

So you basically want to `.update()` here as that is what you are doing, changing the documents that exist. Other operations also make sense `.insert()` to create and `.remove()` to remove the whole document.

BTW. The structure you have is not called an "array" despite the PHP specific notation. These are "nested documents", and arrays are the things within the square brackets: `[]`

Comment: Yes, sorry, i do know it's an object, however dealing with them through the mongo functions, using an array as the selector, I just had my worse messed up :)